# COLNAMES function not reading correct labels

Tags: r, excel

My application reads data from excel into a dataframe. It then transposes the data (thank's excel) and then builds a data frame.

I want to replace the column names assigned during the read process with the contents of the first row.

Here is how I try to replace the column names. It seems like the standard way to do it. However, here is the result:

```
>require(XLConnect)
>wb <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx")
>df1 <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet="df1")
>tdf1 <- t(df1)
>df1<- data.frame(tdf1)
>tdf1 <- NULL
>colnames(df1)
[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5"
> df1[1,]
   X1  X2    X3   X4   X5
LABEL ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE
> colnames(df1) = df1[1,]
> colnames(df1)
[1] "6" "5" "5" "6" "4"
```

I expected colnames(df1) to be

```
 LABEL ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks,
Matt

Here is the data

```
LABEL   CLASS   LOW HIGH    Baseline    MIN MAX SOURCE1 SOURCE2
ONE     TYPE1   10  20                  NA  NA      5   6
TWO     TYPE1   90  100                 NA  NA      7   
THREE   TYPE2   0   0                   NA  NA      8   
FOUR    TYPE3   80  130 120             NA  NA      9   10
FIVE    TYPE3   95  110                 NA  NA      11
```

Comment: Can you show us how the excel data looks like?

Comment: In the excel file, does the column name consist of only one row (or it is merged as one row)?

Comment: Each column name is in the first row a1 = LABEL, a2 = CLASS, a3=LOW etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting the enumerated version of the factors back for each row.

This will work...

```
unname(unlist(df1[1,]))
```